# C++ - Return reference on the calling object

Tags: c++, oop

I'm reading Chapter 7.Classes of C++ Primer by 
Stanley B. Lippman
But i have questions on these codes

```
struct Sales_data{
     string isbn() const { return bookNo;}
     Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);
     double avg_price() const;
     string bookNo;
     unsigned units_sold = 0;
     double revenue = 0.0;
};
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data& rhs){
     units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
     revenue += rhs.revenue;
     return *this;
}
```

What makes me wonder here is the method which return reference on the calling object of Sales_data when we want to change the member of an object.

I think that instead of using this method i can declare a void method, what i understand is when an object call **combine** method, ***units_sold*** is ***this->units_sold*** and **revenue** is ***this->revenue***.

For this reason, i think that i don't have to use a method which return reference on the calling object when i want to change the member of an object.

```
void Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data& rhs){
     units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
     revenue += rhs.revenue;
}
// Also change the function in the struct
```

I have tested it and the void method can still change the member of the object which call combine method.  So is there any differences between these two method ?

Thanks for reading and helping me !

Comment: What would happen if you wants `A = B->combine( C )`?

Comment: I think i'll let B.combine(C) first and then let A = B.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there's no difference.  The use case to consider is when somebody wants to use the result of `combine` to do something else.  For example:

```
Sales_data a;
Sales_data b;
// do stuff
Sales_data c = a.combine(b);
```

This probably commonly comes up mostly commonly with the assignment operator, so that you can do chain asignment.

```
Sales_data a, b, c;
// do suff
a = b = c;
```

It's also a useful pattern when working with an builder-type.

```
Builder b;
b.set_width(10)
 .set_height(100)
 .set_color(blue);
```

Comment: I don't really get it, i think that i can also assign "c = a.combine(b)"  using void method by a.combine(b) first and then let c = a.

Comment: `Sales_order& operator = (Sales_order const &other) { return *this; }` permits chain assignment.  If you return `void` from `operator=`, then you cannot do chain assignment.  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

See this,

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class my
{
public:
    int i;
    my& combine(const my& ob);
};

my& my::combine(const my& ob)
{
    this->i+=ob.i;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    my ob1,ob2,ob3;

    ob1.i=2;
    ob2.i=2;
    ob3.i=2;

    ob1.combine(ob2).combine(ob3); //you can call member of the class of the returned reference 

    cout<<ob1.i<<endl;             //6

    my ob4=ob1.combine(ob2);       // calls copy constructor if present 
    cout<<ob4.i<<endl;             //8

    my ob5;
    ob5 = ob1.combine(ob2);        // call overloaded = operator if present 
    cout<<ob5.i<<endl;             //10
}
```

returning reference or void is your taste, but if you returning reference helpful in some above mentioned situations But nothing wrong if you return void.

Comment: So using method that return reference to calling object is more convenient right ? Because what i see here is that "ob1.combine(ob2).combine(ob3)" can be written to "ob1.combine(ob2)" and "ob1.combine(ob3)" if i use void method